# Python/tkinter - Getting the current value of the checkbox variable

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, callback, widget

I'd like to print the current value of the checkbox variable. Instead I get the last before the click. what am I doing wrong?

```
import tkinter as tk

def widget(frame):
    chbx_value = 0
    widget_col_span = 1

    # widgets checkbox
    var_c = tk.IntVar(master=frame, value=chbx_value)
    widget_c = tk.Checkbutton(master=frame, text='', variable=var_c)
    widget_c.bind("<ButtonRelease>", lambda event: print(var_c.get()))
    widget_c.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=widget_col_span, padx=1, pady=1, sticky="ns")

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('My Window')
widget(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The event `<ButtonRelease>` obviously occurs before your variable has changed. My advice would be to use the `command` kwarg in the `Checkbutton` constructor. Besides, it probably makes more sense to use a boolean as variable:

```
import tkinter as tk

def widget(frame):
    widget_col_span = 1

    # widgets checkbox
    var_c = tk.BooleanVar(master=frame)
    widget_c = tk.Checkbutton(master=frame, text='', variable=var_c, command=lambda: print(var_c.get()))
    widget_c.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=widget_col_span, padx=1, pady=1, sticky="ns")

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('My Window')
widget(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: any way to make it occur after the variable changes using my approach?

Comment: I don't really see how... it would probably be much more convoluted to achieve the same result. Another solution would be to trace your variable instead: `var_c.trace("w", lambda *args : print(var_c.get()))`